# Does Google offer the ability to ban results systematically from certain sources without the -site string?

Tags: search, search-engine

I know the topic of removing www.experts-echange.com has been beaten to death but having to type -site:www.experts-exchange.com is tedious.  Even the ability to auto add strings to a query would solve this problem.  I can probably wrap this into some wget mess but this seems like basic functionality many users would base their search engine of choice on.  If you have discovered some easy method to do this for yourself please let me know.

I imagine there is a really slick toolbar that feeds google your text plus the additional strings you choose.  There is some internal limit to the number of words and or operators Google searches process (with good reason I suppose).

Comment: If not, good idea. Someone could write this up without too much effort.

Comment: While we're at it, I'd like to block Yahoo! answers too. Has anyone ever found a useful answer there? Granted, it's entertaining at times...

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question: but do you want to remove them for their poor answers or the fact that you supposedly need to sign up to read the answers? If the latter, scroll all the way down the page. Took me a while to figure that out, lol.

Comment: Noting for close as ***Not programming related*** - this is a question about web site usage.  Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321618/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Google Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/start.html#sites) allows you to include or **exclude** sites from your search.  You can add a custom search engine to your iGoogle home page.

Answer (score 2):

Google custom search: http://www.google.com/coop/cse/

Comment: That is customized search for your site... am I missing something?

Comment: No, for example: http://www.searchdotnet.com/ allows you to search just .NET sites.

Answer (score 2):

2 easy ways in Firefox:

1. Write a Grease Monkey script.
2. Use a search [keyword](http://www.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/keywords.html). You type the keyword plus a string in the address bar to trigger a search. In this case the URL is http://www.google.com/search?q=-site:expertsexchange.com%20%s. To search on the site your tab is currently in, use javascript:location='http://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=site:'%20+%20escape(location.hostname)%20+%20'%20%S'%20;%20void%200

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to excluding results, I have a greasemonkey script that highlights google search results by domain. I configure subtle colors for a few sites of interest to me, like wikipedia & stackoverflow. But I use red for expertsexchange, which allows me to visually skip right over it.

I can publish my script if there is interest...

If you want to whip up your own script, you need to operate on two kinds of elements. Here are the two XPath expressions that I use:

```
//cite[contains(., '" + domain + "')]/ancestor::li[1]
//span[@class='a'][contains(., '" + domain + "')]/ancestor::div[@class='g']
```

Then I just apply background-color styles to matching elements. Pretty straight forward.